# TeamCity build chain triggering

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, build-automation

In TeamCity (v8.0.1), I have 3 configs: **Build**, **Deploy**, and **Test**

**Build** uses github to compile up to 10 different branches (as specified by the Branch Specifications settings), and is triggered by any github commit.

**Deploy** is a manual trigger, and has an artifact dependency on the **Build** config.  When a user decides it's time to deploy, they can choose any **Build** artifact and they also enter a value for a configuration parameter (which tells a **Deploy** build step which testing server to send the artifact to).

I'd like it so the **Test** config auto-triggers upon **Deploy** finish, and will use the same artifact that **Deploy** used.  Since **Deploy** is a manual trigger, it seems like a proper build chain isn't the solution here, but I could be wrong.  Can someone help out?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the "Finished Build Trigger" type?

Comment: Yes, I have.  The problem I'm up against is that I want Test to use the same build artifact that Deploy does, but I can't figure out how to set it up/use it.

Comment: It seems as if you have to 1) set up an artifact dependency from same chain on **Test**, to depend on **Deploy**. 2) add a trigger to **Test** so that it triggers a build whenever **Deploy** finishes.

Comment: Yeah, it does "seem" like that :) but it's not that straight-forward.  I'm having trouble getting **Test** to pick up the correct artifact.